# Rails cache with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Model

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :num, :foreign_id

   def self.cached_foreign(q)
       Rails.cache.fetch([name,"foreign"+q.to_s]) { where(:foreign_id => q) }
   end

end
```

For the above model, when `Line.cached_foreign(1)` is run repeatedly it always executes the sql statement.

What is wrong here? Ideally, it should return repeated calls from cache.

This seems to work fine when using `find` but not when using `where`.

Comment: is it retrieving fresh records using `find_by_foreign_id` too?

Comment: @Vishal It works fine when using find.

Answer (score 1):

It will work with:

```
where(foreign_id: q).all
```

It's because statement without `.all` is lazily evaluated, so in your cache you store proxy object, which is evaluated when it's really needed. If you add `.all`, you store actual set of records in your cache.

Comment: @Nishant Are you sure you cleared your cache before trying this out?

Comment: same problem as @Nishant  . Using 'all' doesnt help

Comment: @codeObserver it doesn't work the way I described in Rails 4.

Comment: Hey Marek, thanks for answering. Any idea how to resolve this? I tried searching but couldnt figure a good approach.  My use case is to 1] a = User.where(something) 2] ids = User.where(something).pluck(:id) 3] c = a.where.not(ids) . I will like to cache a and c , but just caching 'a' is a performance boost. Thanks for again!

Comment: @codeObserver why don't you ask a question? You could link to your question here, in the comments.

Comment: Handling this in Rails4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199223/rails4-model-caching-low-level-caching